# DoesNotExist Error after flushing database

Tags: python, django

I just flushed my database and deleted the .db file. I ran ./manage.py syncdb --all, and it asked me to create a super user so I did, and I got the following error:

```
User matching query does not exist.
```

We've just started using south. So I tried ./manage.py migrate and ./manage.py syncdb --migrate. They both claim they are making tables, includinga User table, but I continue to get this error. Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the code which generated the error? The line where you are querying the User model to get the user.

Comment: The error means that the user you are trying to get does not exists in the user table with the values you have provided. It does not mean that the tables are not created.

Comment: Well, User.objects.create_user('user', 'user', 'user') throws the error, but so does the initial prompt ('You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.') right after i run the syncdb

Comment: Oddly, this only happens when trying to create a user model. all other models don't throw this error. the user model is custom

Comment: Show your custom user model.